# Keep ListBox sorted, but with a particular entry always pinned to the top

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, listbox

I have a ListBox filled with Countries (which I take from the Active Directory). I want the list to be sorted, but also I want one entry "All" to be at the very top.

How can I do this?

Comment: set the sorted property to false. Add All, add the sorted countries? Unless I'm missing something..

Comment: Thank you all, actually I wrote it wrong. I have a Combobox not a Listbox :( but as a dropdownlist - I guess it would work similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding the data in code behind you can insert a Listitem at index 0.

```
ListItem myItem=new ListItem("ALL","value");
myListbox.Items.Insert(0, myItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would sort the list items first before binding to you ListBox. There are several options for doing this depending on what your data source is i.e. DataTable, List, Dictionary etc. To insert an item use code below.

```
lstCountries.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

After you load the data (i.e Countries), add the ListItem as follows:

```
myListbox.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "All", Value = "" });
myListbox.SelectedIndex = 0; //This line will selected the first item on your ListBox.
```

Here, you might consider which action take if the ListBox with text "All" is selected.