# How to move an element on top (and bottom) of a ListBox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

i've created two buttons ('Move Top' and 'Move Bottom') and I have to make them work as follows. when I click an item from a ListBox (for example, if we have the items: *1. Cat, 2. Dog, 3. Bird, 4. Dinosaur* and *5. Phoenix* in the ListBox) it moves straight to the top or to the bottom.

Let's say I want to move the element *Dinosaur* to the top of my ListBox, and the element *Dog* - to the bottom. How can I make it work? Again - I should make it work by moving it **directly** to the top/bottom.

PS: It's my first day on here so excuse me if my question is not clear enough :)

Comment: What are you using ? WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, ASP.MVC

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Move item in Listbox to the top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309764/c-sharp-move-item-in-listbox-to-the-top)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert an item in a `ListBox` at position 0 (start) you can use:

```
ListBox c = new ListBox();
string item="Some string";
c.Items.Insert(0, item); //added as first item in Listbox
```

if you want to insert it at the end of listbox use:

```
c.Items.Add(item); //add at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MVVM and binding an `ObservableCollection` to your `ListBox`.

You can get the index of the SelectedItem with `IndexOf` and use the Move method of `ObservableCollection`.

```
public void Move(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something similar to this?

```
       public void MoveUp()
    {
        MoveItem(-1);
    }

    public void MoveDown()
    {
        MoveItem(1);
    }

    public void MoveItem(int direction)
    {
        // Checking selected item
        if (yourListBox.SelectedItem == null || yourListBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
            return; // No selected item - nothing to do

        // Calculate new index using move direction
        int newIndex = yourListBox.SelectedIndex + direction;

        // Checking bounds of the range
        if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= yourListBox.Items.Count)
            return; // Index out of range - nothing to do

        object selected = yourListBox.SelectedItem;

        // Removing removable element
        yourListBox.Items.Remove(selected);
        // Insert it in new position
        yourListBox.Items.Insert(newIndex, selected);
        // Restore selection
        yourListBox.SetSelected(newIndex, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
public void MoveToTop(ListBox lb, int index) {
    var item = lb.Items[index];
    lb.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    lb.Items.Insert(0, item);
    lb.Refresh();
}

public void MoveToBottom(ListBox lb, int index) {
    var item = lb.Items[index];
    lb.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    lb.Items.Add(item);
    lb.Refresh();
}
```